# How to save your data

Tags: 18.04

my ubuntu is not working if i install ubuntu again will my previous data be saved.
If not, then tell me any way to save it

Comment: Your original question hasn't been solved, and I asked if you were talking about `steam`. You can mount your disk from a Ubuntu live DVD or USB drive if you wish to reinstall the OS. Your problem is likely fixable in the other question.

Answer (score 3):

You data will not automatically be saved but you can do something yourself.
I don't know what your date refers to. If you want to keep things in your home directory, simply use a live CD or USB to preform the following command:

> tar zxvf home_bk.tar.gz /home

and then use mv command to move it to a safe place and restore it after reinstalling the system.(this is actully working for any dicectory)

If your want to restore your settings, find the file and cp it to a safe place.Replace it after reinstalling.

Comment: +1 for the Very good comment. :)

Comment: please tell me how can i save data on ubuntu hard disk in windows , Ubuntu hard disk not showing on windows

Comment: Well, as you know, Ubuntu or most other Linux system uses ext4 file system as default. But in Windows, as far as I know, there's no method to directly read file in this kind of file system. As a result, you may not be able to mount the partitions that using ext 4 file system so you can't copy files in Windows to another place. It's recommended that you make a Live Ubuntu USB( This is pretty easy in Windows. ) to do the back up work. And the USB will be very useful if you want to reinstall your system. Hope this can be helpful to you. :-)